# Does ChromeIPass synchronise passwords across your devices?

Tags: password-management

I love Keepass, but find it difficult to keep my Keepasses in sync (for example if I change a password in work, I need to manually update my Keepass database at home).

I have found the [ChromeIPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeipass/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae) Chrome addon, and my question is does ChromeIPass synchronise the database across the various devices I am signed into Chrome to with my Google account (work PC, home PC, Nexus 7 etc)?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't by default. If you want to synchronise you have to use something like Dropbox, SugerSync or Google Drive.

There a special Google Drive plugin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kp-googlesync/files/) but any syncronisation solution should work.